# Using chained observables in transform pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, observable

I am facing issue while chaining observables in transform pipe. I have bank info with account number which is encrypted. I want to decrypt that account number and show.

In console it shows the decrypted account number but it displays only encrypted one.
pls help

```js
    public transform(bankId: any, name: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
    return this.supService.getBankById(bankId).pipe(
      switchMap(
        (bInfo: {
        data: {
          bankInfo: {
            accno;
          };
        };
      }) => {
        if (bInfo.data.bankInfo.accno) {
          const encodedAccountNumber = bInfo.data.partyBankInfo.accountNumber;
          this.supService.unProtectBank(encodedAccountNumber).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              console.log("Unencrypted data======>", data);
              bInfo.data.bankInfo.accno = data;
          });
        }
        return of(bInfo);
      }),
      map(
        (info: {
          data: {
            bankInfo: {
              accno;
            };
          };
        }) => {
          console.log("Bank Info==============>", bankInfo);
            if (name === 'accountNumber') {
            return info.data.bankInfo.accno;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `switchMap` operation returns `of(bInfo)` immediately without any chance for you inner call to finish and update the value.

What you need to do is replace the content of your `switchMap` with:

```js
if (bInfo.data.bankInfo.accno) {
  const encodedAccountNumber = bInfo.data.partyBankInfo.accountNumber;
  // Do not subscribe here
  return this.supService.unProtectBank(encodedAccountNumber).pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      console.log("Unencrypted data======>", data);
      bInfo.data.partyBankInfo.accountNumber = data;
      // Return something out of the Observable
      return bInfo;
    })
  );
} else {
  return of(bInfo);
}
```

The key thing here are the `return` statements and the removal of `subscribe` in favour of `pipe`.

Comment: Basically I want to merge my unencrypted account number in original bInfo object here if I return this service I am only getting encrypted value in response where as I want entire Bank object

Comment: @GauravMatta the code I posted should be the one in your first `switchMap` operation. It's not the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

return the `upProtectedBank` Observable and use `tap` operator instead of `subscribe`.

```js
switchMap(
        (bInfo: {
        data: {
          bankInfo: {
            accno;
          };
        };
      }) => {
        if (bInfo.data.bankInfo.accno) {
          const encodedAccountNumber = bInfo.data.partyBankInfo.accountNumber;
          return this.supService.unProtectBank(encodedAccountNumber).pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
              console.log("Unencrypted data======>", data);
              bInfo.data.bankInfo.accno = data;
              return bInfo;
          }));
        }
        return of(bInfo);
      }),
```

Comment: Basically I want to merge my unencrypted account number in original bInfo object here if I return this service I am only getting encrypted value in response where as I want entire Bank object

Comment: @JsNgian That won't work because then in the `if` branch you are returning an `Observable<any>` with only the unencrypted data, you are never returning the enriched `bInfo`.